# Jobs getting skipped in GitHub Actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

Even on a `push` event, my last 2 jobs are getting skipped. Why?

```yaml
name: Testing

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  job-one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]'

    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-two:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-one
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && (success() || failure())

    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-three:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-two
    if: success() || github.event_name == 'push'

    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-four:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-three
    if: github.event_name == 'push'

    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-five:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job-four

    steps:
      - run: exit 0
```

- Job 1 needs to run only on PR and doesn't need to be run if the PR is from Dependabot
- Job 2 runs only on PR and must run even if Job 1 fail, because one of its step checks whether or not Job 1 failed
- Job 3 runs only if Job 2 is successful or skipped
- Job 4 runs only on push, requires Job 3 to be successful
- Job 5 follows Job 4, running only on push and only if 3 and 4 are successful

Comment: Because 5 needs 4, and 4 need 3, and 3 needs 2 and 2 needs 1. "If a run contains a series of jobs that need each other, a failure or skip applies to all jobs in the dependency chain from the point of failure or skip onwards."


see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds

Comment: @aknosis How should I modify my `if:`s/`needs:` then?

Comment: My advice would be to split this up into multiple workflows. One that triggers off of `push`, the other `pull_request`. You will have duplication but if that is a concern once you have those working then you can look into reusable actions or workflows. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems to be a lot of hassle for a small problem in my opinion... See my own answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I did the following:

- Step 4:

  ```yaml
  if: github.event_name == 'push' && !failure() && !cancelled()
  ```

  Because if it's not a failure and not cancelled it's either `success()` or skipped.
- Step 5: Same thing. I added the `if:` condition to make sure it would behave the same as the previous step, even though there might exist some sort of inheritance I didn't dig through.